# Data/Resource for adjectives related to nouns

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, adjectives, wordnet

I am looking for resource or some way(maybe using multiple resources) which can help me figure out which adjectives to use. For example:

1. weight > 40 : heavier
2. age > 40 : older

I am not sure how to express it in words but I think the example is clear. Is there any resource like word net for this?  I am currently interested only in numeric quantities and comparative adjectives, excluding adjectives like "good" and "best".

I came across this cool paper https://uwnlp.github.io/verbphysics/ but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: So you're asking for a list of English noun / adjective pairs? Is it always about numerically quantifiable properties? "Color" clearly relates to "blue", "taste" to "bitter; bland; sweet": do you include those kinds of adjectives? There are also pairs like "pork, pig: porcine" and "elephant(ine)", not to mention "cat" and "cat-like", which expands the list quite a bit. Are you only looking for comparative adjectives, thus excluding "good" and "best"?

Comment: Yes, I am currently interested in only numeric quantities and comparative adjectives. Anything to start with will help.

Comment: So maybe you should clarify what you're asking in the question, since comments go away.